# Finding last hour value with same ID (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, max

I need to create a new column that identify the last hour row for same ID but I can not lose the other rows of same ID.

May you help me?!

Thank you!!

Current Data:

```
ID      Date    Hour
1562    13Oct   11:00
1562    13Oct   15:00
1562    13Oct   22:00
```

Desired Result:

```
ID      Date    Hour    What I Need (new column)
1562    13Oct   11:00   0
1562    13Oct   15:00   0
1562    13Oct   22:00   1
```

Comment: Could you post your data as text instead of photos? And are you doing this in DAX or Power Query/M?

Comment: Is this over the entire ID or for each day?

Comment: Hi I'm trying in Power Query.

For entire ID! I can not lost any row because then I need to sum all rows that contain "1" and all rows that contain "0"

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
ID      Date        Hour
1562    2019-10-13  11:00
1562    2019-10-13  15:00
1562    2019-10-13  22:00
1563    2019-10-13  15:00
1563    2019-10-13  22:00
1562    2019-10-14  11:00
```

You can create this using the steps below:

```
ID      Date        Hour    Max_Row
1562    2019-10-13  11:00   0
1562    2019-10-13  15:00   0
1562    2019-10-13  22:00   1
1563    2019-10-13  15:00   0
1563    2019-10-13  22:00   1
1562    2019-10-14  11:00   1
```

1. Group by `ID` and `Date`, add two new columns called `All_Rows`
   using the All Rows-operation and `Max_H` using the Max-operation on
   Hour.
2. Expand all rows for `All_Rows`.
3. Add a conditional column that is `IF Max_H = all_rows.Hour THEN 1 ELSE 0`.
4. Remove the columns you don´t need.

This was all done using the UI, but the code looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(// code genereted from pasting above values //)

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Date"}, {{"All_Rows", each _, type table [ID=number, Date=date, Hour=time]}, {"Max_H", each List.Max([Hour]), type time}}),
    #"Expanded All_Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All_Rows", {"ID", "Date", "Hour"}, {"All_Rows.ID", "All_Rows.Date", "All_Rows.Hour"}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded All_Rows", "Max_Row", each if [All_Rows.Hour] = [Max_H] then 1 else 0),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Conditional Column",{"All_Rows.Date", "All_Rows.ID", "Max_H"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Note that the max is calculated for both `ID` and `Date`, but I think you can figure out what to do If you want to do it only for `ID`.